# forward the response of http request to the client

Tags: node.js, axios, azure-functions

I am invoking a web service through an azure function in node.js with Axios, I have a couple of questions here.

1-  in the body of this request I'm hardcoding the value for `appUser`. however, if I want to run this request on postman and pass the JSON value in the body for `appUser`what changes do I need to do in the code so the param value can pick up what is being passed.

2- the response for this request is only returned in the console of the editor but not getting sent to the client response body (i.e. postman) any idea how to forward the response?

```
module.exports = async function () {
const axios = require("axios");
const data = {
appUser: "yamen",
};
const headers = {
Authorization:
  "Basic WUFNkVQRDg9",
};

{
axios
  .post(
    "https://tegossl/GetAppUser?company=Enva",
    data,
    { headers: headers }
  )

  .then((response) => {
    console.log(`Status: ${response.status}`);
    console.log("data: ", response.data);
  })

  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    });
    }
   };
```

Comment: Can you explain how your function will be invoked? Does it really have no parameters?

Comment: it's an HTTP trigger azure function that could be invoked with an HTTP request and in my case, it's a post request.

Comment: Can you share an example of how that POST request looks? In particular, does it contain the necessary parameters `appUser` and `company`? But then why are these parameters not present in your function (`function(appUser, company)` instead of `function()`)?